# Am trying to build a git branch other than master on travis

Tags: python, git, travis-ci

Am trying to build a git branch other than master on travis. But travis only lists master. How do i get travis to list all my branches in the linked ripo.[Here is my repo](https://github.com/alimulondo/level-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the branch [tdd](https://github.com/alimulondo/level-up/tree/6fb3c426dedab4abdaf0e577deba0297c0a58c93) you've named the file `travis.yml` while it must be `.travis.yml`. Rename, commit and push.

In other branches you don't have `.travis.yml` at all. Add `.travis.yml` to all branches you want to build.

Comment: thanks very much! It works fine when i fix that. But travis lists only master branch?

Comment: What do you mean "lists"? Travis builds any branch you push to Github that is allowed to build. You can [enable or disable branches](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#building-specific-branches) by patterns, enable/disable tags and pull requests.